# Stick-breaking: break sticks of decreasing lengths

Tags: stochastic-processes, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes, slice-sampler

The stick-breaking construction used for Dirichlet Processes can create an infinite sequence of probabilities $ \boldsymbol{\pi} $ (stick lengths) that sum to 1 via the following formulae:

$\nu_i \sim Beta(1, \alpha) \quad \pi_i = \nu_i \prod_{j<i} (1 - \nu_j) \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, 3, \dots $

The resulting stick lengths are unordered. Teh *et al* order them for the stick-breaking construction of the Indian Buffet Process ( https://proceedings.mlr.press/v2/teh07a.html ), but those sticks do not sum to 1.

Here is the question: can we construct a usable stick-breaking process that generates sticks of decreasing lengths and that sum to 1?

The first thing that came to mind is something like this:

$ \pi_i = \nu_i \pi_{i-1} \left( 1 - \sum_{j<i} \pi_j \right) $

Would that be usable though for inference? I'm thinking slice sampling for nonparametric models.